React native error when I use an array instead of a single element
I wrote this code in react native.
but when I run it, I only get an error. What is wrong? It does seem that I am close to the answer. I've tried everything, but it is still not working.

export default function App(){

const couleurs=["blanc", "jaune", "gris"];
const col="jaune";

return(
  
<View>
  <Image
    source={require("./assets/"+couleurs[1]+".png")}
  />
</View>

);
}


But if i use col instead of couleurs[1] it works perfectly.

export default function App(){

const couleurs=["blanc", "jaune", "gris"];
const col="jaune";

return(
  
<View>
  <Image
    source={require("./assets/"+col+".png")}
  />
</View>

);
}


But I need to use the string value of an element from the array.
Can you help me please.

You can check the React Native docs here, where it specifies that

In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

This means that you cannot dynamically create a source string (this is on purpose, due to the nature of static media), but rather it must be contained in a variable or known beforehand, they go on to give this example:
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
const icon = this.props.active
  ? 'my-icon-active'
  : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
const icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;

